# Incompatibility error in SQLAlchemy. Is there anything I am doing wrong or haven't done?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I am now learning software engineering in a bootcamp hence I have no real world experience in software and web development.

I ran the ff
`$: cat 7-dump.sql | mysql -uroot -p`

To check if all tables are created, I ran
`echo "quit" | HBNB_MYSQL_USER=hbnb_dev HBNB_MYSQL_PWD=hbnb_dev_pwd HBNB_MYSQL_HOST=localhost HBNB_MYSQL_DB=hbnb_dev_db HBNB_TYPE_STORAGE=db ./console.py`

Summary of Error

```
...
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (3780, "Referencing column 'city_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'places_ibfk_1' are incompatible.")
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE places (
    city_id VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    user_id VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, 
    description VARCHAR(1024), 
    number_rooms INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    number_bathrooms INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    max_guest INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    price_by_night INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    latitude FLOAT, 
    longitude FLOAT, 
    id VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(city_id) REFERENCES cities (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users (id), 
    UNIQUE (id)
)
```

I checked the cities.py and place.py to see if there was a mismatch in field type but I found no mismatch.
cities.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""city class"""
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from models.base_model import BaseModel, Base
from models.place import Place


class City(BaseModel, Base):
    """This is the class for City
    Attributes: state_id: The state id
        name: input name
    """
    __tablename__ = "cities"
    id = Column(String(60), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
    state_id = Column(String(60), ForeignKey('states.id'), nullable=False)
    places = relationship("Place", cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan',
                          backref="cities")
```

places.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""place class"""
from os import getenv
import models
import shlex
from models.base_model import BaseModel, Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Table, String, Integer, Float, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


place_amenity = Table("place_amenity", Base.metadata,
                      Column("place_id", String(60),
                             ForeignKey("places.id"),
                             primary_key=True,
                             nullable=False),
                      Column("amenity_id", String(60),
                             ForeignKey("amenities.id"),
                             primary_key=True,
                             nullable=False))


class Place(BaseModel, Base):
    """This is the class for Place"""
    __tablename__ = "places"
    city_id = Column(String(60), ForeignKey("cities.id"), nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(String(60), ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(1024))
    number_rooms = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    number_bathrooms = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    max_guest = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    price_by_night = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)
    amenity_ids = []

    if getenv("HBNB_TYPE_STORAGE") == "db":
        reviews = relationship("Review", cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan',
                               backref="place")

        amenities = relationship("Amenity", secondary=place_amenity,
                                 viewonly=False,
                                 back_populates="place_amenities")
    else:
        @property
        def reviews(self):
            """ Returns list of reviews.id """
            var = models.storage.all()
            lista = []
            result = []
            for key in var:
                review = key.replace('.', ' ')
                review = shlex.split(review)
                if (review[0] == 'Review'):
                    lista.append(var[key])
            for elem in lista:
                if (elem.place_id == self.id):
                    result.append(elem)
            return (result)

        @property
        def amenities(self):
            """ Returns list of amenity ids """
            return self.amenity_ids

        @amenities.setter
        def amenities(self, obj=None):
            """ Appends amenity ids to the attribute """
            if type(obj) is models.Amenity and obj.id not in self.amenity_ids:
                self.amenity_ids.append(obj.id)
```

I manually checked the field types of my cities table and it is same as the sqlalchemy code. Also there is no place table in my database.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE cities;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id         | varchar(60)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                   |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| name       | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| state_id   | varchar(60)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Please any help?

Comment: The contents is longer than the number of characters allowed in comments. So I'd have to put them in parts

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS hbnb_dev_db;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS hbnb_dev_db;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'hbnb_dev'@'localhost';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'hbnb_dev'@'localhost' = 'hbnb_dev_pwd';
GRANT ALL ON hbnb_dev_db.* TO 'hbnb_dev'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON performance_schema.* TO 'hbnb_dev'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

```

Comment: USE hbnb_dev_db;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cities`;
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `state_id` (`state_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cities_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `states` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;